# "неделя, другая" и "партию-другую" — синонимичны ли варианты с запятой и дефисом?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, дефис

Из справочника Розенталя, [параграф 9](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=97#pp97), пункт 1:

> Различаются внешне похожие конструкции; ср.: *Для завершения работы над проектом понадобится **неделя, другая*** (при втором однородном члене предложения опущено слово *неделя*); *Сыграем **партию-другую*** (сочетание, близкое к сложному слову, а не перечисление однородных членов).

Являются ли варианты с запятой и дефисом синонимичными? Можно ли было бы поменять выделенные выражения на "неделя-другая" и "партию, другую" соответственно?

Comment: Первый пример очень неудачен: *Для завершения работы над проектом понадобится одна неделя, другая неделя.* Тогда скажут просто "*понадобится две недели*". В оригинальном справочнике этот пункт звучит так: Следует различать внешне похожие случаи: *Прошла неделя, другая* (второй однородный член выражен не полностью — «другая неделя»). — *Сыграем партию-другую* (сочетание, близкое к сложному слову, а не перечисление однородных членов).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Это разные выражения**: по смыслу, написанию, интонации.

(1) Прошла **неделя-другая,** никаких сведений об отце нет. [И. С. Карпов. По волнам житейского моря. Воспоминания (1970-1975) // «Новый мир», 1992]

...ведь пройдет **неделя-другая**, и густым шатром зелени покроется дубрава, где он растет, и тогда уж к нему не пробиться солнцу. [М. Мазуренко. 1970]

В первом случае мы обозначаем примерное количество времени, написание через дефис, произношение без паузы.

Вопрос № 249920
Почему десяток-другой пишется через дефис?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Через дефис пишутся все подобные сочетания, обозначающие примерное количество, примерное число: год-другой, месяц-другой, раз-другой и т.п. Написание следует запомнить, а проверить можно при помощи орфографического словаря.

(2) Но прошла **неделя, другая** ― и я не выдержал тоже. [Л. Корнилов. Не бойтесь языка химических формул // «Химия и жизнь», 1965]

Прошла **неделя, другая**, рассудок не покидал Анастаса. [Виктор Курочкин. Последняя весна (1968)]

Во втором случае ставится запятая: прошла неделя, потом другая. Это однородные отношения, перечислительная интонация; так изображается длительное течение времени.